# Examples of well-written scientific papers in mathematics

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, article-writing

I am looking for examples of papers, which are (according to you) an example of good mathematical writing, while I would be interested in some sort of justification what makes you believe so.

For instance, I tend to believe that writing short sentences in words rather than symbols appears to be more beautiful to me. However find the right balance on this is difficult because it can be annoying some times.

On the other hand, I have seen papers from great mathematicians which don't seem to adapt this sort of idea in writing. I understand that we tend to overanalyze things that have been struggling us for awhile and sweep under the rug others, that probably are more serious for our convention but we believe that are obvious.

To finish this off, I am not looking for justification like "The font size is beautiful", or "I like his/her style because is my mathematical-idol and I like the mathematics they do". Apparently the paper you will post would have some relation with mathematics you like, and the font is not so important (for me). I would like to see justification regarding the writing and only this. Of course welcome is every book or online handout that has to do with mathematical writing at this level and you think is useful.

Thank you!

Comment: "Of course the question has not just one answer and definitely each individual has their own way to write out things."  By definition, your description of your question is pretty much the MSE description of a question that is too broad.  Any answer also would be primarily-opinion based, as would any voting on or acceptance of, any one answer.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732988/does-a-good-explanation-constitute-a-proof/2733005#2733005

Comment: Paul Halmos's essay on writing mathematics is a classic. I don't agree with everything he says, but a lot of it is very useful to think about. See http://mathtourist.blogspot.com/2010/07/paul-halmos-on-writing-mathematics.html

Comment: @amWhy. But one suspects that the question will be answered and enjoyed by the community. Perhaps MSE isn't doing a great job describing what questions it enjoys. The de jure law is that we don't like broad questions. The de facto law is that we only enforce the de jure law when we don't like a question that is broad.

Comment: [Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/) always had good advice (and links to more advice.)

Comment: In the postscript, you mention books "for undergraduate students only." You also say they "oversell mathematics"--what does that mean? I wonder if you have looked at any books like this one: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf

Comment: @DavidK: +1 on the Knuth book recommendation. I also like Gillman's "Writing Mathematics Well".

Comment: Thank you for comments all! @amWhy the reason I wrote out this paragraph, is exactly to avoid having this sort of feedback. I thought that despite my title, reading my question would be understood that am seeking for examples of well-written papers along with the personal opinion of those who want to share some of their tips. Clearly this is primarily-opinion based answer. And frankly although it is not the write place to discuss this, I DON'T know why this is frowned upon on this site. I can find out of the $\sim$10^6 questions many thousands of non-hold questions with opinion-based answers.

Comment: @DavidK What do I mean is what I wrote. If you believe is wrong you can change my opinion by posting one counterexample like the one that you posted probably. "Oversell", means useless verbosity, while "for undergrads", I mean that the question is not about how to write calculus 1 exams, but how to present a good scientific mathematical result. These two things are not necessarily correlated.

Comment: Hope this question survives, looking forward to hopefully some answers, cannot of anywhere else on the internet (with as qualified a readership) one could even think of asking such a thing, seems sometimes that rigidity in letting something stay on the site is prioritised too stringently over the benefit that the answer population provides, even if the question does not pass all of the tests on a binary basis.Have a lot of sympathy with @Mason 's comment. Pbbly an unpopular opinion and will be chastised, but still, thanks for asking, hopefully can read some of the suggestions that come!

Comment: Examples of the use of "oversell" ([see a definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oversell)) are an airline overselling seats (assuming some people will book but not fly), or when someone, in order to get more sales of a product, claims it has merits that it actually does not. I can imagine several ways in which someone might "oversell" mathematics, but I wondered specifically which one you had in mind. I never would have imagined that it meant "useless verbosity," which to me implies specifically that someone is using a lot of extra words that do not say anything new,

Comment: I see that the question has been improved so as to address my earlier comments. I'll try to remember to come back and delete them later.

Comment: This is gonna be my last comment at this forum, since I am no longer willing to give even a small amount of my time (perhaps no one cares about it) for it. I have commented again a year ago, that mathematical police is accepted, nonetheless I believe that many times this certain police prefers to read threads  suspiciously carrying over this site their non-mathematical personality (of course this is depicted in their comments, which many times are ironic or embarrassing). I believe that closing this question is off the regulations of logic and not of this site.

Comment: If I was interested, I am (more than) 100% sure that I could go to the profile of each one of the "moderators" (or whatever they are anyway) who voted to get this question closed and find out questions that they have either posted or have given an answer and their quality is similar with mine. Anyway, I believe that this question can be hosted somewhere where the police is more rational! Cheers!